# Particles sent into the same direction with uniformly distributed speed

Tags: pr.probability, recreational-mathematics, physics

Fix a positive integer $n$. Every second, a particle is sent along a straight line from a fixed position in a fixed direction, at a random integer speed chosen uniformly in $\{1,\ldots, n\}$ meters per second. The particles move in a continuous manner (we assume everything is happening in  $\mathbb{R}^3$). If two (or more) particles ever collide, they both get annihilated.

In terms of $n$, what is the probability $p_n$ that some particle survives forever? Even if there is no exact formula for $p_n$, can the values of $\lim\inf_{n\in \mathbb{N}}p_n$ and $\lim\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}p_n$ be determined (hopefully they are the same value)?

Only one question needs to be answered for acceptance.

Comment: What if three or more particles collide at the same time?

Comment: What if a particle is released at time 0 traveling at speed 1; and a new particle is released at time 1, traveling at speed 10. Do they “collide” between time 1 and time 2 or do they not collide because they never occupy the same site at the same (integer) time. If the former, I think it should be pretty easy to show that almost surely nothing survives. If the latter, I think the answer should be the same, but the proof may be a bit more involved.

Comment: And to simplify particles with speed $0$ can be omitted. They all get annihilted at position 0. As a consequence speed should be chosen uniformly in $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

Comment: Thanks for your questions for clarification - I will edit the original post so that the questions are answered.

Comment: Brittany Dygert, Christoph Kinzel, Matthew Junge, Annie Raymond, Erik Slivken. Jennifer Zhu. "The bullet problem with discrete speeds." Electronic Communications in Probability 24  1--11, 2019. https://doi.org/10.1214/19-ECP238 
https://scholarworks.umass.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2294&context=math_faculty_pubs

Comment: Also related (bullets with continuous speeds): "The combinatorics of the colliding bullets" by Broutin and Marckert: https://doi.org/10.1002/rsa.20869 (and its references and citations).

Comment: @AnthonyQuas - I am interested in why our intuitions are so different. My intuition is that the probability that some particle survives is one ... for a start, the probability that the first particle has speed $n$ is $1/n$, and it will survive, so that's a (bad) lower bound for the probability. For $n=2$, the problem is equivalent to a one-dimensional unbiased random walk, where nothing surviving means the random walk never revisits the origin - I think the probability of that is zero? And from that, I extrapolate to any $n$ (ha ha).